# How to extract the layout (topview Design) of the building from the given input image

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

[image]Here Basically I have an image (satellite view of any area). I have to detect Roads , Buildings , Trees from the image. 
After detection all three from the image , i have to get the layout of the building.

```
The approach for Building Detection from satellite images which i tried is 
-> Converting the image into Gray Scale
-> From the Gray Scale using OTSU Thresholding
-> From that converting white pixels to co-ordinates and store it as CSV
-> But it is not giving the accurate Results 


Similarly For Road Detection I used Terrain Images 
-> Direct approach which i used is  Canny Edge Detection
```

**Can Anyone Please give a good Solution for my Problem Statement
Thanks in Advance.**

Comment: I don't see no image...

Comment: can anyone help with my question.